# Map(value set using spring beans) is empty when I try to access using Rest URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, singleton

I am new to Spring Beans. I am trying to set entry `map` using `beans.xml` file and accessing that value using GET REST request.

beans.xml

```
<bean name ="book" id="book" class=" org.test.model.Book" scope = "singleton">
    <property name="id" value="123" />
    <property name="bookName" value="FirstBeanBook"></property>
</bean>
<bean name="bookservice2" id = "bookservice" class="org.test.service.BookService" scope="singleton">
    <property name="bookMap">
        <map><entry key="123" value-ref="book" /></map>
    </property>
</bean>`
```

In Main class,

```
BookService bookService = (BookService) context.getBean("bookservice2");
bookService.getMap().toString(); // here it is working fine.`
```

I guess when I am trying to access this map using GET request it is creating another instance of `BookService` class which has empty `bookMap`.

Please provide some solution to get same result when I use GET request of REST.

Edit:
Handling get request as

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/getBook/{id}")
public Book getBook(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    return bookService.getBook(id);
}
```

BookService.Java

```
`public class BookService {
static Map<Integer, Book> bookMap = new HashMap<Integer, Book>();
//This class has Getter setter of bookmap too.
public BookService() {}

public Book getBook(String id) {
    return bookMap.get(Integer.parseInt(id));
}`
```

Comment: This is normal Spring Beans config, which you say is working - how are you exposing this for access through GET? Can you show that code?

Comment: Added.Please check

Comment: I'm surprised this worked for you earlier - if you instantiate the field in your class, there is no point of using Spring. You need to just declare it and expose a getter for it. Also, why static?

Comment: Reason for static and instantiation is : if I access bookMap using get request it gives null pointer exception(if i dont instantiate.). I guess It creates new BookService object when i call it using url . So as to get the value of bookMap as i entered in beans.xml I used static.

Comment: Can you show how you are getting bookservice instance here? 
 return bookService.getBook(id);
Is it autowired or you are creating new BookService() in that controller class?

Comment: I made bookService singleton class